# По нажатию на кнопку получить Math.random()

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Даны 2 инпута и кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку нужно получить результат операции, задействующий  `Math.random()` и значения, стоящие в инпутах.

Подскажите другие варианты если можно.

```js
function f() {
  let a = inp.value;
  let b = inp1.value;

  document.write(Math.round(inp.value + Math.random() * inp1.value))
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
<input type="text" id="inp1">
<button onclick="f()">ok</button>
```

Comment: вы сами пробовали найти решение?

Answer (score 0):

Пример реализации:

```
function f() {
    const input1 = document.getElementById('id1');
    const input2 = document.getElementById('id2');

    const result = Math.round(input1.value + Math.random() * input2.value);

    const textarea = document.getElementById('someTextarea');
    textarea.innerText = result;
}
```

Для того, чтобы функция `getElementById()` работала, необходимо присвоить атрибут `id` HTML элементу. Это наиболее предпочтительный способ, так как если использовать `getElementsByClassName()`или `querySelector()`, то при изменении атрибута `class` придется менять исходный код на Javascript.

Comment: Предположим, я хочу получить рандом из диапазона `[2; 5]`. `Math.random()` возвращает значение от 0 до 1, допустим сейчас `Math.random()`  вернет `0.9999`, тогда результат такого решения будет корректным?

`const result = Math.round(2 + Math.random() * 5);`

Comment: Math.round(2 + Math.random() * 5);  получить рандом из диапазона так пишется

Comment: На сайте [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) есть статья для функции `random()` с примерами. В вашем случае код будет выглядеть следующим образом `Math.round(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 2`

Comment: @Moco, тестирую в браузере - возвращает 6, видимо  *получить рандом из диапазона **не** так пишется*

Comment: да тоист диапазон от2-до5 будет  const result = Math.round(2 + Math.random() * 3);